# how to implement string handler in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a string handling in my laravel project, and I got the result that using string handler explode function but I don't know how can I implement that result in the view page, can anyone has to help me?
I am a beginner in  php laravel the code will be shown below,

At controller

```
function subscriptionpack(Request $request)
{

    $sub = subscription::all();
    $details = subscription::get('details');
    $string = $details;
    $str_arr = explode (",", $string);
    return view('admin/adm_pricingtag',["sub"=>$sub,"str_arr"=>$str_arr]);
}
```

at blade.php

```
@foreach($sub as $sub)
   <h1>{{$sub->title}}<h1>
   <h2{{$sub->price}}</h2>
   <ul>
  @foreach($str_arr as $val)
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>{{$val}}</b></li>
  @endforecah
  </ul>
@endforeach
```

here the second forecah `@foreach($str_arr as $val)` not working properly, it shows all row values and also shows table field name, I want the result in the loop by loop

the result is shown below

[{"details":"first row value 1
first row value 2
first row value 3"}
{"details":"second row value 1
second row value 2
second row value 3"}
{"details":"therd  row value 1
therd  row value 2
therd  row value 3"}]

]

Comment: $details is not a string, what are you trying to do?

Comment: $details is a string, that has many data that are separated by a comma,
I am trying to separate this data using with string handing function explore, and its work, but I can't show that details in the view page properly

Comment: get('details') does not return a string and you are using it as one, is it a column on your subscription model?

Comment: yes it is a column in subscription model

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to made an Accessor for it. In your `Subscription.php` model do the following.

```
public function getDetailsAsArrayAttribute() {
    return explode (',', $this->details);
}
```

Instead you can now access `details_as_array` on your model and it should work.

```
foreach($sub as $sub)
  ...
  @foreach($sub->details_as_array as $detail)
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>{{$detail}}</b></li>
  @endforeach
  ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Secondly your coding style is inconsistent, Subscription should be with capitol beginning as it is a class and overall it seems quickly written.